# Steps to cause Windows to recognize a new VLAN IP address once PC has a reservation on that subnet

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

We are using the following:

- *Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard* as the OS for an isolated network domain server
- The isolated network hosts two subnets: VLAN-370 and VLAN-640.
- Dell Optiplex 3070 - Windows 10 PCs are hosted on this domain.

An IPv4 reservation for VLAN-370 was granted by the server using the following information:

[image]

The server is set up to allow a PC with a reservation to connect based on ***PC name*** and ***MAC address***.  However, after using Windows 10 utilities ( `Control Panel->...->System -> System Properties` <kbd>Change</kbd> button to set the PC name, as well as ensuring Member of Domain: is set correctly, and connecting the network cable to the PC Ethernet port, the PC never connects.

We have tried using `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`, then tried pinging the DNS server, which fails. We cannot see any indication of PC being connected to the domain.

Are there command line calls that can be made to force the PC to see the new domain?

Comment: You seem to be confusing two things: Having a functioning network and being a member of the domain. In order to join the domain the computer MUST have a working network that can see the domain controller first. And ipconfig /join doesn't even exist. Get the network sorted first. See what ip-address the computer gets from the DHCP (are you using DHCP ?). Is routing working between both VLANs ?

Comment: I’m having trouble figuring out what exactly is the problem. Does the PC not receive any IP address at all via DHCP? Or does it receive a different IP address? Are VLANs actually involved as far as the PC is concerned? Or is a switch responsible for the VLANs and the PC isn’t doing 802.1q?

Comment: @Tonny - re `/join` edited to say `/renew`.  `DHCP` is one of the roles that are defined, and in the expandable tree, both subnets, including VLAN-370 are defined under `DHCP Server` branch, but we statically assign IP addresses, it is not done dynamically.

Comment: @DanielB - After doing the steps I described, we use a `cmd` prompt and enter ipconfig -all to see what IP addresses show up.  We are seeing ***168***.xxx.151.xxx, when we are expecting to see ***172***.23.37.xxx.

Comment: @Tommy - regarding _MUST have a working network that can see the domain controller_, The network does work, there are over 100 PCs currently hosted, all working fine.  We have compared the Windows 10 setup screens on the PC we are trying to install against the same screens on working PCs, and all of the configuration settings look correct.

Comment: A colleague here saw the same phenomena when attempting to add a PC to this network a few weeks ago and said rebooting several times finally caused something to work, and the PC connected.  That description is very unsatisfying to me however, so would like to see if there is something more definitive I can do, i.e. a set of steps eg using `ipconfig` to troublshoot.  I have by the way attempted to reboot several times, with no luck.

Comment: ***New commenters***, Please be patient - I have to leave my station for awhile, but will tag you in a reply as soon as I am able to return..Thanks...